# I would like to open up Here Map Api through an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, here-api

I am trying to open the official Here Map app through an intent in Android. For instance if I have an address as a destination I wish to know if there is also a way to launch the navigation. That is something I found out I can do in Google Maps something like google.navigation:q={address}&mode=d. If anyone knows the secret recipe please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty good reference for you:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/mobility-on-demand-toolkit/topics/navigation.html

Comment: Thanks a lot David. That is self explanatory.